# If $p>3$ and $x^2+3y^2=p$, prove $\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1$ and $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-reciprocity, legendre-symbol

> If $p>3$ and $x^2+3y^2=p$, prove $\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1$ and $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$.

$$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)$$

We know that $$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)= \left(\frac{p}{3}\right)\times (-1)^{(p-1)(3-1)/4}= \left(\frac{p}{3}\right) \times (-1)^{(p-1)/2}$$

**Can anyone explain how we get from:**

$$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=(-1)^{(p-1)(q-1)/4}$$ to

$$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\times (-1)^{(p-1)(q-1)/4}$$

Using [3/p Legendre Calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608481/prove-that-for-p-3-frac-3p-1-when-p-equiv-1-11-pmod12-and)

I see that they get answer modulo $12$, not $6$.

I can see that $x^2\equiv -3y^2 \pmod{p} \Rightarrow (xy^{-1})^2\equiv -3 \pmod{p} \Rightarrow -3$ is Q.R. (since $y \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ is not true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because if $p\neq q$, then $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)}$.

If $p>3$ and $x^2+3y^2=p$, then, for contradiction, let $p\mid y$. But then $p\mid p-3y^2=x$, so $p^2\mid x^2,y^2$, so $p^2\mid x^2+3y^2=p$, contradiction. Therefore $\gcd(y,p)=1$, so $$x^2\equiv -3y^2\pmod{p}\iff \left(xy^{-1}\right)^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}\implies \left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1$$

By [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B13) (QR) Lemma (see below) this is equivalent to $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, and since $p>3$ and $p$ is odd, we get $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$.

The QR Lemma: If $p>3$, then $\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1\iff p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Proof: If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1\iff p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$

If $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=-\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=1\iff p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$

Comment: So if they gave us $p>20$, the answer would be $p \equiv 1\pmod{21}$?

Comment: @AnnoyingEpsilon We could still only conclude that $p\equiv 1\pmod 6$. If $p>20$, then there can still be many values $p$ can get $\bmod 21$. The reason we have mod $6=2\cdot 3$ here is because you can see $3$ in $x^2+3y^2=p$ and the $2$ is because $p\not\equiv 0\pmod{2}\implies p\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, i.e. there can only be one value $p$ can get mod $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, so we use the CTR on 1mod2 and 1mod3 to get the result

Comment: @AnnoyingEpsilon That's right.